# C - separating name and surname using comma with strtok

Tags: strtok

I have a problem with strtok. I'm trying to separate the first name from the last name using a comma. When I try using scanf and type "Vincent,Van Gogh", it returns Vincent as the first name, but the last name only returns Van.

However, when I use a preset string, it shows the last name as Van Gogh.

```
printf("Enter name and surname: ");
char name[100];// = "Vincent,Van Gogh";
char firstname [100];
char lastname [100];
char* token;

scanf("%s", &name);
token = strtok(name, ",");
strcpy(firstname, token);
token = strtok(NULL, ",");
strcpy(lastname, token);

puts(firstname);
puts(lastname);
```

Is there something I'm missing in order to make the user input work?

Comment: This seems ok, using a preset string rather than a user-inputted string should not effect the end result if both strings are equal

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I got it. printf() only scans until the first whitespace, hence why it didn't account for "Gogh". Using fgets() fixed it.